# Missing required keys after submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the form for creating new school in city which doesn't work on creating; it returns me an error with undefined parameter `:id` for `city_path`.

```
<% if controller.action_name == "edit" %>

    <% if @school.errors.any? %>
        <div class="errors alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                <% @school.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= form_for @school, url: school_path(@school) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label "Ime:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control input-field" %>

        <%= f.label "URL slike:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :icon_url, class: "form-control input-field" %>

        <%= link_to school_path(@school), class: "btn btn-default", "data-no-turbolink": true do %>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> &nbsp; Nazad
        <% end %>

        <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-default") do %>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp; Pošalji
        <% end %>

    <% end %>

<% else %>

    <% if @school.errors.any? %>
        <div class="errors">
            <ul>
                <% @school.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= form_for @school, url: city_schools_path do |f| %>

        <%= f.label "Ime:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control input-field" %>

        <%= f.label "URL slike:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :icon_url, class: "form-control input-field" %>

        <%= link_to city_path(@city), class: "btn btn-default", "data-no-turbolink": true do %>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> &nbsp; Nazad
        <% end %>

        <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-default") do %>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp; Pošalji
        <% end %>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

When I try to send the form I get this error:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cities", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

This is my `city_controller`:

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @cities = City.all
    end

    def show
        find_city
        @schools = @city.schools.all
    end

    def new
        @city = City.new
    end

    def edit
        find_city
    end

    def update
        find_city

        if @city.update(city_params)
            redirect_to city_path(@city)
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    def create
        @city = City.new(city_params)

        if @city.save
            redirect_to index_path
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    private

    def find_city
        @city = City.find(params[:id])
    end

    def find_schools
        @schools = @city.schools.all
    end

    def city_params
        params.require(:city).permit(:name, :icon_url)
    end

end
```

And this is `school_controller`:

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        find_city
        @schools = @city.schools.all 
    end

    def new
        find_city
        @school = @city.schools.new
    end

    def create
        find_city

        @school = @city.schools.new(school_params)

        if @school.save
            redirect_to school_path(@city, @school)
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def show
        find_school

        @search = @school.users.ransack(params[:q])
        @city = @school.city

        if (params.has_key?(:q))
            @users = @search.result
        else
            # Prikazivanje svih korisnika koji su iste generacije kao i
            # poslednji dodati korisnik
            #@users = @school.users.where(generation: User.last.generation).order("sclass ASC")
            #@sclasses = @school.sclasses.where(generation: Sclass.last.generation).order("name ASC")
            if Sclass.last.nil?
                @sclasses = @school.sclasses.all
            else
                @sclasses = @school.sclasses.where(generation: Sclass.last.generation).order("name ASC")
            end
        end
    end

    def edit
        find_school
    end

    def update
        find_school

        if @school.update(school_params)
            redirect_to school_path(@school)
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    def destroy
        find_city
        find_school

        @school.destroy
        redirect_to city_path(@city) 
    end

    private

    def find_city
        @city = City.find(params[:city_id])
    end

    def find_school
        @school = School.find(params[:id])
    end

    def school_params
        params.require(:school).permit(:name, :icon_url)
    end

end
```

Here is the school show view:

```
<% title "#{@school.name}" %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center city-title">
        <h3><%= @school.name %></h3>
    </div>
</div>

<%= search_form_for @search, url: school_path(@school) do |f| %>
    <div class="row input-field">
        <div class="text-center">
            <%= f.text_field :full_name_cont, placeholder: "Pretraga učenika" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-field">
        <div class="text-center">
            <%= f.select :generation_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(@school.users.order("generation DESC").select(:generation).uniq, "generation", "generation", @search.generation_eq), {}, { :class => "selectpicker" } %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row input-field">
        <div class="text-center">
            <%= f.submit "Traži", class: "btn btn-default" %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <%= link_to city_path(@school.city), class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> &nbsp; Nazad-->
            <% end %>

            <% if is_admin? %>
                <%= link_to edit_school_path(@school), class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> &nbsp; Uredi školu
                <% end %>

                <%= link_to new_school_sclass_path(@school), class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Dodaj razred
                <% end %>

                <%= link_to new_school_generation_picture_path(@school), class: "btn btn-default" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Dodaj tablo
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="users">
        <% if !@users.nil? %>

            <% @users.in_groups_of(4, false).each do |users| %>

                <div class="row">

                    <% users.each do |user| %>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                            <a href="<%= user_path(@city, @school, user.sclass, user) %>" class="thumbnail school" data-no-turbolink="true">
                                    <%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:thumb), size: "100", class: "user-profile-image img-responsive" %>
                                    <%= user.full_name %> <br/> 
                                    <span class="badge">
                                        <%= show_user_class(user.sclass.name) %>
                                    </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>

                </div>

            <% end %>

        <% else %>

            <% @sclasses.in_groups_of(4, false).each do |sclasses| %>

                <div class="row">

                    <% sclasses.each do |sclass| %>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                            <a href="<%= sclass_path(sclass) %>" class="thumbnail school" data-no-turbolink="true">
                                <%= image_tag sclass.icon_url, class: "img-responsive" %>
                                <%= show_user_class(sclass.name) %>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>

                </div>

            <% end %>


        <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

Routes:

```
                       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                  
Controller#Action
                         root GET    /                                            
welcome#index
                        index GET    /pocetna(.:format)                           
welcome#index
                     new_cart GET    /korpa(.:format)                             
carts#new
                      success GET    /poslato(.:format)                           
carts#success
                     sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                          
sessions#create
                  new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                      
sessions#new
                      session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                      
sessions#destroy
                        login GET    /prijava(.:format)                           
sessions#new
                      prijava POST   /prijava(.:format)                           
sessions#create
                       logout GET    /odjava(.:format)                            
sessions#destroy
                       odjava DELETE /odjava(.:format)                            
sessions#destroy
              school_sclasses GET    /skola/:school_id/razred(.:format)           
sclasses#index
                              POST   /skola/:school_id/razred(.:format)           
sclasses#create
            new_school_sclass GET    
/skola/:school_id/razred/dodaj(.:format)     sclasses#new
                  edit_sclass GET    /razred/:id/uredi(.:format)                  
sclasses#edit
                       sclass GET    /razred/:id(.:format)                        
sclasses#show
                              PATCH  /razred/:id(.:format)                        
sclasses#update
                              PUT    /razred/:id(.:format)                        
sclasses#update
                 school_users GET    /skola/:school_id/ucenik(.:format)           
users#index
                              POST   /skola/:school_id/ucenik(.:format)           
users#create
              new_school_user GET    
/skola/:school_id/ucenik/dodaj(.:format)     users#new
                    edit_user GET    /ucenik/:id/uredi(.:format)                  
users#edit
                         user GET    /ucenik/:id(.:format)                        
users#show
                              PATCH  /ucenik/:id(.:format)                        
users#update
                              PUT    /ucenik/:id(.:format)                        
users#update
                              DELETE /ucenik/:id(.:format)                        
users#destroy
   school_generation_pictures POST   /skola/:school_id/tablo(.:format)            
generation_pictures#create
new_school_generation_picture GET    /skola/:school_id/tablo/novi(.:format)       
generation_pictures#new
      edit_generation_picture GET    /tablo/:id/uredi(.:format)                   
generation_pictures#edit
           generation_picture GET    /tablo/:id(.:format)                         
generation_pictures#show
                              PATCH  /tablo/:id(.:format)                         
generation_pictures#update
                              PUT    /tablo/:id(.:format)                         
generation_pictures#update
                 city_schools POST   /gradovi/:city_id/skola(.:format)            
schools#create
              new_city_school GET    
/gradovi/:city_id/skola/nova-skola(.:format) schools#new
                  edit_school GET    /skola/:id/uredi(.:format)                   
schools#edit
                       school GET    /skola/:id(.:format)                         
schools#show
                              PATCH  /skola/:id(.:format)                         
schools#update
                              PUT    /skola/:id(.:format)                         
schools#update
                       cities POST   /gradovi(.:format)                           
cities#create
                     new_city GET    /gradovi/novi(.:format)                      
cities#new
                    edit_city GET    /gradovi/:id/uredi(.:format)                 
cities#edit
                         city GET    /gradovi/:id(.:format)                       
cities#show
                              PATCH  /gradovi/:id(.:format)                       
cities#update
                              PUT    /gradovi/:id(.:format)                       
cities#update
                        carts GET    /carts(.:format)                             
carts#index
                              POST   /carts(.:format)                             
carts#create
                    edit_cart GET    /carts/:id/edit(.:format)                    
carts#edit
                         cart GET    /carts/:id(.:format)                         
carts#show
                              PATCH  /carts/:id(.:format)                         
carts#update
                              PUT    /carts/:id(.:format)                         
carts#update
                              DELETE /carts/:id(.:format)
```

Also, form is submitting `:id` and `:format` parameters forming weird URL (*http://localhost:3000/skola/1.17*).

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I had the error in `schools#create`:

`redirect_to school_path(@city, @school)`

It had to be:

`redirect_to school_path(@school)`